# TypeScript array initalization with subscribe

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to return an array from this TypeScript function (written within Angular).

I've tried a number of different approaches. I've tried having a public variable in the class that gets initialized with courses (say the variable was called public fallCourses : xCourse[] and in the function below it'd have this.fallCourses = courses), I've tried typing return before 'courses' within the function call below, etc. Pretty simple operation, just can't get it to work.

```
getFallCourses(){

    let fallCourses : xCourse[];
    this.dataService.getFallCourses().subscribe((courses: xCourse[]) => {
            fallCourses = courses;
    });  
    return fallCourses;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The observable is completing after the function returned, so it just replaces local scoped `fallCourses`. If you need this like it is, then you should return an array, which is **filled** in subscription. Here's a snippet:

```
getFallCourses(){
    let fallCourses: xCourse[] = [];

    this.dataService.getFallCourses().subscribe((courses: xCourse[]) => {
        fallCourses.push(...courses); // will change the fallCourses itself
    });  

    return fallCourses;
}
```

But it's better to use the observable itself, just by subscribing to it from the caller.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but this returns an array of size 0. I guess I could put all of my code in the subcribe() function. What I’m trying to do is see if a certain string is present in the array that’s returned, and all I need to return from this is a Boolean.

Comment: It will return an empty array, which will be filled during the `subscribe()` method. If you need the data right after calling `getFallCourses()`, then you must to change your code and put your logic inside the `.subscribe()`.

Comment: Ok. If I do that, I need to pass in a string to the subscribe function and then have it return a Boolean if the string is in that array. Is it possible to do this with this syntax?

Comment: Well I'm sure that it can be done with Observables, but I need to see the code to say how it can be changed to support the observables. As a reference you can check [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/observables). Also you can check [here](How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?), which has a comprehensive answer.